# Pull data from database every second

Tags: java

I want to create a Java code which makes benchmark about importing xml file into SQL table. I tried this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Application extends SqlUtils {

    private static String folderPath = "D:\\EntityImportEversana";

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Running file verifier");
        System.out.println("monitoring folder " + folderPath);
        SqlUtils sql = new SqlUtils();

        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        Path path = Paths.get(folderPath);
        path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println("Event kind:" + event.kind() + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
                if(event.kind().equals(StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE)){
                      Instant start = Instant.now();
                
                      // make here call every second to get the status
                      HashMap<String, List> map = sql.checkFileImport();

                      Instant end = Instant.now();
                      System.out.println(Duration.between(start,end));

            }

            }
            key.reset();
        }

        watchService.close();
    }
}
```

Do you know how I can make a call every second to DB and get the status?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
while(true) { // repeat code within indefinitely
     while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
         // do stuff
     }
     Thread.sleep(1000); // get executing thread to sleep for 1000millis - 1s
}
```

Should work

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow are expected to have some explanation, not just code snippet.

Comment: comments added to help provide explanation. Any better?